# error links of pagination by using chuck for rows and column

Tags: laravel-5, pagination, chunks

I'm trying to use pagination for a loop that chunk items according to columns and rows of bootstrap but can not use pagination

```html
@foreach ($courses->chunk(3) as $courses)
 <div class="grid-col-row">
     @foreach ($courses as $course)
         <div class="grid-col grid-col-4" style="margin-top: 30px">
             <div class="course-item" >
                 {{$course->image}}
             </div>
         </div>
     @endforeach
 </div>
 @endforeach

<div class="page-pagination clear-fix">
     {{$courses->links('Pagination.default')}}
 </div>
```

Controller :

```html
class CourseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $courses = Usecourse::where('activated', 1)->paginate(15);
        return view('courses.courses-list')->with([ 'courses' => $courses]);
    }
}
```

have an ERROR :
(2/2) ErrorException
Method links does not exist.

Comment: add controller details please

Comment: other wise we can't help

Answer (score 0):

If you have Doubt Laravel pagination Please

Read

**https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination**

Comment: you can't use chunk